# is there a certain word to describe these songs?

Tags: rhythm

i’ve noticed in some songs there will be a part where it sounds like someone speaking from a old television, or just speaking in general and then the music starts playing again. here are some example in songs.
sixteen - no doubt 2:04-2:19
no role modelz - J. Cole 2:42-2:58
temptation - joey badass 0:00-0:18
is there a certain word that categorizes these songs ????

Comment: I don't think there is a term for these specific songs but it is a version of sampling.

Comment: Voting to keep open because aaliyah is asking for a term for a musical practice and citing examples, not so much asking for analysis/transcription *of* a limited set of songs.

Answer (score 3):

I'm unaware of any word *for* samples specifically of extended clips of spoken word (besides "sampling", which also covers musical samples and even samples less than a second long). There's certainly not a word for that "categorizes" such songs themselves, because many genres use such extended spoken segments, whether sampling other works or as original material.

There are words for other instances of speech in music, but not specifically the use you're thinking of. In hip hop, [skits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hip_hop_skit) are extended interludes of dramatic dialogue.

In some 20th-century art song, *[Sprechstimme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprechgesang)* describes a sort of half-singing-half-speaking that uses changes in vocal pitch without sticking to musical notes.

Comedic genres have often included "patter" sections; Bobby Darin can spend one minute joking before 30 seconds of singing:

... and the concept comes to an extreme in the genre of "[Talking blues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talking_blues)," and the comedy-routine-with-a-chorus "Alice's Restaurant":

And of course, opera has a centuries-old love-hate relationship with "talking," resulting in the recitative and eventually musical theatre. (If *Hamilton* is essentially "through-rapped," with very little dialogue outside of any musical numbers, is it a musical, or a hip hop opera?)